# Springboot health check is always down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot health. I just want to make it up every time. So i add below,

```
@Component
public class AggregationHealth implements HealthIndicator { 
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        Health health = Health.up().build();
        logger.info("----------------------------Health status : " + health.getStatus() + "----------------------------");
        return health;
    }
}
```

The log show status Up but when i access my application using below url it says Down.

```
http://localhost:8085/health
```

I also added below in my pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edit:

Once i add `"endpoints.health.sensitive=false"` it gives me below descriptive error,

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "aggregationHealth": {
    "status": "UP"
  },
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "free": 371498577920,
    "threshold": 10485760
  },
  "mongo": {
    "status": "DOWN",
    "error": "org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]"
  }
}
```

So i since the mongo is down, i add a mongo db details in my application.properties file. But my question is, my service does not need a mongodb. 
I even add `spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=false` too.
In that case how can i make the health Up with out specify mongo details?

Comment: Add the full json of the output here please (and make sure you are authenticated). Something else states your app is down probably.

Comment: well the response json is just {  "status": "DOWN" }. Since i dont use any spring security or anything i don't authenticate my requests. So is it a must that i need to authenticate my requests?

Comment: You can add the property "endpoints.health.sensitive=false" to get the full output without authentication.

Comment: That should be the default if no security is in place: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health-access-restrictions

Comment: If he uses 1.3.0. With 1.2.7 it's not the default (and i suspect, that's the used version).

Comment: well endpoints.health.sensitive=false helps me to find the issue.  find the edit answer please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either remove the dependency to Mongo, or if you only want to disable the Health indicator for MongoDB, add the following property:

```
management.health.mongo.enabled=false
```